# How to achieve parallel edges in two way directions in d3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

HI I'm trying to achieve parallel links in the d3 force layout.

[image]
Below is my code

```
function tick() {

  link.attr("d", linkArc);
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
function linkArc(d) {

  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = (d.straight == 0)? Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy): 0;

  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y +
      "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

But still i'm getting curved links. Please refer this as sample http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that you are still drawing SVG arc paths. Draw line paths if you want a straight line.

Something like:

```
return "M" + d.source.x + "," +  d.source.y + "L" + 
       d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
```

However that is only part of the solution. Arcs naturally separate the incoming and outgoing edges. Lines do not. So the above return looks something like:

[image]

Not bad, but not the parallel lines you want. For real parallel lines, you need to do some additional math. You don't really want your lines aimed at a central point in the nodes, but points equally offset from the center, along a line perpendicular to the incoming edge. There are examples out there of how to do the math. Adapting [one of them](https://bl.ocks.org/ramtob/3658a11845a89c4742d62d32afce3160), I get:

[image]

[Here it is running in a live sandbox.](http://plnkr.co/edit/WazMlXdLgU31BNSLogIS?p=preview) If you change the constant `conincidentLines` to a true value an you'll get the first result. Otherwise the parallel example.

Comment: Solid -- Answer

Comment: this is my json data :{
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314}
   
  ],
  "links": [
{"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  0},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2}

  ]
} But its not working for me

Comment: Is there any problem with my data

Comment: HI got it . Problem is with conincidentLines = true in my code.

Comment: How to avoid overlap the conincidentLines links while dragging?

Comment: Is your drag handler manually setting the source and target points? If so, it will need to do the same kind of "find the offset points" math that the force tick handler does. As you can see in the sandbox example, it doesn't need it because it uses the built in `force.drag`.

Comment: Or, if you mean the do-si-do lines do when dragging, that's a result of the "rightward" determination that determines which line is on top. During some drags, that decision flips, if the source->target orientation switches rightward to leftward. There is no super-easy way to avoid that, since the lines are drawn independently. Instead of the simple dynamic rightward evaluation, you would need to keep track of all the edges and depend on stored, not evaluated, rightwardness. Often in d3.js, small display tweaks can require a great deal of added algorithm complexity.